# How to setup initial state for react-redux from API results

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm writing this application which checks for current products based on the user that is logged in. I've written a redux action that checks for the current products for that user but I don't know how to implement it. Could someone help me out?

**PS If I dispatch the action to check for the current product inside the component did mount lifecycle method then react creates an infinite loop and I only want to check for the products if the user is signed in because otherwise I can't retrieve any products.**

---

This is the code for my redux action that checks for new products of the user:

```
import { CHECK_PRODUCTS_STARTED, CHECK_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS, CHECK_PRODUCTS_FAILURE } from './types'

const getProducts = () => {

    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(checkProductsStarted())

        let config = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            body: `token=${getState().auth.token}`
          }

        // Get database products
        const { products: dbProducts } = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/getProducts', config)
            .then(async res =>  await res.json())
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(checkProductsFailure({error: typeof(err) === "string" || err ? err.toString() : "Error"}))
            })

        // Get current products in state
        const { products: stateProducts } = getState().products

        // Only add products that arent already in the state:
        const unqiueProducts = dbProducts.filter(product => stateProducts.includes(product))

        // Add them to payload
        dispatch(checkProductsSuccess(unqiueProducts))
    }
}


const checkProductsStarted = () => {
    return {
        type: CHECK_PRODUCTS_STARTED
    }
}

const checkProductsSuccess = (products) => {
    return {
        type: CHECK_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
            products
        }
    }
}

const checkProductsFailure = (err) => {
    return {
        type: CHECK_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
        payload: {
            ...err
        }

    }
}

export default getProducts
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180627/in-a-redux-reducer-if-state-is-not-defined-can-you-immediately-return-the-init/60181346#60181346

Comment: I think we should diagnose why you're getting an infinite loop. Can you show your component?